# mimetypes.mime_guess() on google app engine behaves strange

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mime, webapp2

In my python shell, i can do

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type("ulla.svg")
('image/svg+xml', None)
```

And it behaves as expected, however, running the same code (or at least, this equal example) on google app engine, it returns `(None, None)`

```
class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        import mimetypes
        self.response.out.write(mimetypes.guess_type("ulla.svg"))
```

Am i doing it wrong? :)

**BTW** - It's python 2.7 in my macbooks shell, and also 2.7 on app-engine

Comment: I encounter the same issue with .docx, .xlsx, .webm, aind many other file extensions:  guess_type working fine in dev environment, and returning None in Google App Engine.

Comment: The workaround I found was to take the mimetypes.types_map dict from dev env, and use a hand made guess_type function that does a get() on this dict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.svg` is not included in the default `types_map` embbeded in the `mimetypes` module:

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> print '.svg' in mimetypes.types_map
False
```

`mimetypes` module add additional extension/mimetypes from [system files](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/mimetypes.py#l40), and svg is defined on most distribution in `/etc/mime.types`

```
$ cat /etc/mime.types  | grep svg
image/svg+xml                   svg svgz
```

But unfortunately it is not defined in the App Engine sandbox.

You should fill a defect on the [public issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry)

As a workaround you can register the mimetype yourself with `mimetypes.add_type`

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type("ulla.svg")
(None, None)
>>> mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svg")
>>> mimetypes.guess_type("ulla.svg")
('image/svg+xml', None)
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification and workaround :) - but, does this really count as a defect?

Comment: I could also be viewed as a feature request :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could directly edit C:\Python27\Lib\mimetypes.py:

Insert `'.svg' : 'image/svg+xml'` in the `types_map` dictionary.

credit: [source](http://morkrispil.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/svg-support-for-app-engine-running-python-on-windows-xp/)